# Can't get Visual Studio to allow access to the winrt::Microsoft::UI::Windowing namespace

Tags: c++, winui-3

I am running VS 2019. The project I am trying to create is a WinUI 3 app that is just one Window which contains a frame which is used to navigate over many pages. I have these nuget packages installed:

1. Microsoft Project.Reunion
2. Microsoft Project.Reunion.Foundation
3. Microsoft Project.Reunion.WinUI
4. Microsoft Windows.CppWinRT
5. Microsoft Windows.SDK.BuildTools

I believe I need to install the Microsoft WindowsAppSDK to get that namespace. When I do install that nuget package, VS warns me that it was already installed times 3. Seems to be a conflict with something. Any ideas? Do I have the correct packages installed? Do I need other ones installed? Any help is appreciated.

I need access to AppWindow in this namespace so I can get access to the main window and change its size, get position, change the title and color the titlebar.

Comment: You should get rid of all 'Microsoft Project.Reunion" packages, "Project Runion" was the code name for WinApp SDK so yes, it probably conflicts with Microsoft.WindowsAppSDK package

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/winui/winui3/xaml-templated-controls-cppwinrt-winui-3#prerequisites

Answer (score 0):

It's not only the NuGet package. You also need to install some work loads. You can get the steps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/set-up-your-development-environment?tabs=cs-vs-community%2Ccpp-vs-community%2Cvs-2022-17-1-a%2Cvs-2022-17-1-b).

You also need to consider Visual Studio 2022. Visual Studio 2019 only supports Windows App SDK 1.1 and earlier

Comment: It did not work. I will consider upgrading to VS 2022 later. Right now, I have enough chaos in my getting my project to work. On to how it failed. So I uninstalled the Project Reunions, all of them from the project I was using. I wanted a fresh start so I created a new project for App (WinUi 3 in Desktop) and when I did this,  the Project Reunions where back in my nuget packages for the project. I then went back to the project selections in VS and this is where I discovered Reunion was still one of the code bases at the bottom of the description. Something doesn't smell right. Removing things.

Comment: So, I rechecked my nuget packages and Extensions and found that I still had Project Reunion extension installed. Then I checked VS Templates as to why there was some with Reunion listed. I found that clearing the selectors and trying again to find a project, I got a lot more possibilities. I finally found one that was correct, as I did not want reunion or UWP. I selected the Blank App, Packaged (WinUI 3 in Desktop); it almost worked. I really needed VS 2022 to get the best benefit. I will probably upgrade once I get my project working again. I down graded WindowsAppSDK to 1.5 and PT to 1.42.

Comment: I think I am now back on track. I now have my correct namespace which was the original problem. Thanks for the help and suggestions. I hope VS 2022 is just as good as VS2019 or better.

Comment: [Visual Studio 2019 only supports Windows App SDK 1.1 and earlier. Visual Studio 2022 is recommended for developing apps with all versions of the Windows App SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/set-up-your-development-environment?tabs=cs-vs-community%2Ccpp-vs-community%2Cvs-other%2Cvs-2019#visual-studio-project-and-item-templates). @kerplatz does AndrewKeepCoding 's answer work for you?